# Shortcut to focus code in overlay (peek) editor (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

With VS Code, you can open an overlay editor to peek at the references (Shift+F12) or the definitions (Alt+F12):
[Peek References Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9mth.png)

With that overlay open, I can navigate on the right side, which shows the list of the found references/definitions.

But how can I focus on the left side to scroll through the code with arrow keys?
And focus back to the list?

Of course, you can click with the mouse in the window, but I try to work with the keyboard only.

I could not find a key binding in the keybindings.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some hunting but I think I figured it out.

(1) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> moves focus from the list of references on the right to the selected reference on the left.

The problem is then that  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> will not then move focus back to the right panel 0 because you are in an  editor but the command

```
Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus
```

[bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> by default]

will activate the Tab/Shift+Tab through UI elements functionality.  So

(2) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> will move focus from the code in the left panel to the right panel.

The `Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus` will remain on until you toggle it off with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> again - there is a Status Bar button `Tab Moves Focus` that appears when it is active.

---

And then I found an "easier" way.  The command

```
togglePeekWidgetFocus
```

appears to toggle between the left and right peek reference view panel!

It is bound to the rather unwieldy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Fn2</kbd> keybinding though so you may want to rebind to something else like (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "alt+r",       // whatever you want here
  "command": "togglePeekWidgetFocus",
  "when": "inReferenceSearchEditor || referenceSearchVisible"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+k f2",
  "command": "-togglePeekWidgetFocus",
  "when": "inReferenceSearchEditor || referenceSearchVisible"
}
```